# About key value observers in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hello i am very new to the iPad programing.Can any one explain me how to use key value observers in iPad.i need to check if a particular variable value is changed and based on that i trigger one method.One approach is to use NSTimer to continuously check the variable value but i know this can be done better by using key value observers so please help me understand key value observers concept.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific: which property of which object do you want to observe?

Comment: Hi Jilouc. I have one NSNumber object whose value is changed several times in different methods of the class i want to call one method each time the value of the NSNumber is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have declared a property `@property (retain) NSNumber myNumber;` in your interface.
Then you can observe value changes with KVO.

Observe changes (put this in your `init` method for example)

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myNumber" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Then implement the following method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myNumber"]) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

And remove the observer in the dealloc method:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myNumber"];
```

You can refer to [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) for further information.